# Can't find control within asp.net repeater?

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I have the following repeater below and I am trying to find lblA in code behind and it fails. Below the markup are the attempts I have made:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptDetails" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td><strong>A:</strong></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="lblA" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
</table>
```

First I tried,

```
Label lblA = (Label)rptDetails.FindControl("lblA");
```

but lblA was null

Then I tried,

```
Label lblA = (Label)rptDetails.Items[0].FindControl("lblA");
```

but Items was 0 even though m repeater contains 1 itemtemplate

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You need to set the attribute `OnItemDataBound="myFunction"`

And then in your code do the following

```
void myFunction(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
   Label lblA = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblA");
}
```

Incidentally you can use this exact same approach for nested repeaters. IE:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="outerRepeater" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="outerFunction">
<ItemTemplate>
   <asp:Repeater ID="innerRepeater" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="innerFunction">
   <ItemTemplate><asp:Label ID="myLabel" runat="server" /></ItemTemplate>
   </asp:Repeater>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

And then in your code:

```
void outerFunction(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
   Repeater innerRepeater = (Repeater)e.Item.FindControl("innerRepeater");
   innerRepeater.DataSource = ... // Some data source
   innerRepeater.DataBind();
}
void innerFunction(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
   Label myLabel = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("myLabel");
}
```

All too often I see people manually binding items on an inner repeater and they don't realize how difficult they're making things for themselves.

Comment: I'm a little confused.  What I am actually doing is when I click on a View details link on 1 page, it takes me to a detailed view on another page which has the repeater and in page_load, I am trying to locate lblA

Comment: Edited. Hopefully that explains a bit more.

Comment: Ok, what I ended up doing was moving a DataTable variable to the top level of  class.  Then I created the ItemDataBoundEvent and in there I checked for the lblA in the repeater and if it found it, set it to some text I got back from a row in the DataTable.  Am I correct in my understanding of this?  Thanks

Comment: I guess a simple question is, why it was return 0 items when I had 1 item template?

Comment: I'm not really sure. I never access items directly in a repeater so I'm not sure how they behave.

Comment: I have a some controls inside a repeater. Everytime there is a postback, I have to rebind it before I can access the controls. Is there any way to call the `ItemCreated` function to retrieve the controls without binding it again?

Comment: @SiKni8 - I couldn't tell you. It's been so long since I've used ASP.Net Forms I don't remember the magic behaviors which drive this sort of thing. :(

Comment: It is okay. It was just a mess to deal with it. I just manually populated the fields and makes life so much easier. Thank you :)

Answer (score 8):

I just had the same problem.

We are missing the **item type** while looping in the items. The very first item in the repeater is the **header**, and header does not have the asp elements we are looking for.

Try this:

```
if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {Label lblA = (Label)rptDetails.Items[0].FindControl("lblA");}
```

Comment: thanks man, I have the same problem and I spend so much time to figure out the problem. SO is great !!

Comment: ditto - this really should have been included on MSDNs own example... but what should we expect from that huh??

Answer (score 2):

Code for VB.net

```
    Protected Sub rptDetails_ItemDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterItemEventArgs) Handles rptDetails.ItemDataBound    
      If e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem Or e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item Then
        Dim lblA As Label = CType(e.Item.FindControl("lblA"), Label)
        lblA.Text = "Found it!"
      End If
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Investigate the [Repeater.ItemDataBound Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemdatabound.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You should bind first.
for example)

```
rptDetails.DataSource = dataSet.Tables["Order"];

rptDetails.DataBind();
```