# Asp.Net / C# - How to get the Text of a Label control nested inside a Repeater?

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I am trying to get the text of my label which is inside a repeater, but I keep getting a `NullPointerException`.

All of the data is coming from database and it is coming correctly.

When I click on the LinkButton, I want to use the Label Text for next bit code.

Aspx page:

```
   <asp:Repeater ID="RepeaterDepartmentParent" runat="server">
       <ItemTemplate>
                <div id="outerDiv" class="col-lg-3 col-xs-6" runat="server">
                        <!-- small box -->
                        <div>
                            <div class="inner">

                                <p>
                                   <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Department_Namestr")%>
                                </p>
                            </div>


                            <asp:Label ID="lblDepartmentId" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Department_Idint")%>' Visible="true"></asp:Label>

                            <asp:LinkButton ID="linkChildDepartment" CommandName="Click" runat="server" CssClass="small-box-footer" OnClick="linkChildDepartment_Click">More info<i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></asp:LinkButton>

                        </div>
                </div><%--<%-- ./col -->--%>
       </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:Repeater>
```

Code Behind:

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataSet dsParentDepartment = null;
        dsParentDepartment = objDepartmentBL.viewDepartmentparent();
         RepeaterDepartmentParent.DataSource = dsParentDepartment.Tables[0];
        RepeaterDepartmentParent.DataBind();

    }

  protected void linkChildDepartment_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //what to write here??
        //i have tried the bellow code but it gives me every data in that loop but i
        //want the single data for a link button click.
        //foreach (RepeaterItem item in RepeaterDepartmentParent.Items)
       // {
          //  Label myLabel = (Label)item.FindControl("lblDepartmentId");
         //   myLabel.Text = Id;
        //}
       //edited code that works properly
        LinkButton linkChildDepartment = (LinkButton)sender;
        RepeaterItem item = (RepeaterItem)linkChildDepartment.NamingContainer;
        Label myLabel = (Label)item.FindControl("lblDepartmentId");

    }
```

How can I correctly reference the Link Button Label Text?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't find control within asp.net repeater?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1203316/cant-find-control-within-asp-net-repeater)

Comment: yes probably but these make me confused on that line "You need to set the attribute OnItemDataBound="myFunction"" and i dont want to use OnItemDataBound.. if you see the answer there we dont need to use that. we only need to use NamingContainer Thats all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `NamingContainer` property to get the reference of the `RepeaterItem`. From there it's a short way to your label:

```
protected void linkChildDepartment_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton linkChildDepartment = (LinkButton) sender;
    RepeaterItem item = (RepeaterItem) linkChildDepartment.NamingContainer;
    Label myLabel = (Label)item.FindControl("lblDepartmentId");
     // ...
}
```